# mvn clean test ... terminal output doesn't show some characters

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, character-encoding, charset

Here is my pom.xml file

```
        <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
    
...

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=${project.build.sourceEncoding}</argLine>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <includes>
                        **/TestRunner*.java
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

And my sample cucumber step class

```
@When("test")
    public void searchToSplitFind(int index){
      System.out.println("ç,ğ,ş,ö,Ç,Ğ,Ş,İ,Ö");
}
```

So when i run this command on terminal `mvn clean test -D"cucumber.filter.tags=@OCR3"`

My output is

```
ç,?,?,ö,Ç,?,?,?,Ö
```

Finally my encoding.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="Encoding" defaultCharsetForPropertiesFiles="UTF-8">
    <file url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/src/main/java" charset="UTF-8" />
    <file url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/src/main/resources" charset="UTF-8" />
    <file url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/src/test/java" charset="UTF-8" />
    <file url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/src/test/java/features/OCR.feature" charset="UTF-8" />
    <file url="PROJECT" charset="UTF-8" />
  </component>
</project>
```

P.S = I use windows and intelliJ idea

Comment: Windows command line encoding is not the same as in IntelliJ IDEA. It's likely not UTF-8 by default.

Comment: Yes but when i run **intcl.cpl** and then **administrative** and **change system locale** and tick **Beta:Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support** but this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this. It should work.

```
mvn clean test -DargLine=“-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8”
```

At the end you can append cucumber arguments

Comment: `mvn clean test -DargLine="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" -D"cucumber.filter.tags=@OCR3"` i run this command but still same

Comment: Ok is it working fine with in IntelliJ? I mean without mvn

Comment: Did you try to write the output to a file? E.g. 
`PrintWriter o = new PrintWriter(                    "file.output", "UTF-8");            o.println("ç,ğ,ş,ö,Ç,Ğ,Ş,İ,Ö");            o.close();`

Comment: Yes file.output worked fine. But mvn clean test still same

Comment: Can you please remove maven-surefire-plugin from pom.xml and  encoding.xml file and try again with command I have mentioned.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work